# How can I fix this update error

Tags: command-line

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ug.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
```

Comment: Try using the main server. Go to Dash, type and open 'Software and Updates' and on the 'download from' dropdown, choose the main server. Then try updating again.

Comment: show the content of you `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: Are you using a proxy or an ISP that filters your internet connection? `wget -S http://ug.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources` should return a 404 error code not 403.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

In the URLs, where you have `ug` change to `us`, like http://ug.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ with http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Then update with:

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: I have already done this before but still I get the same error

Comment: @MazingaAdam show the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and it might work fine this way.